# Calculate tx fees via Blockfrost or any other provider?

Tags: plutus, haskell, blockfrost, fee

Is there a way to calculate transaction fees without having to go through cardano-cli? Maybe something like Blockfrost? or any other API providers? I don't want to run a local node to do that.

Comment: If you don't want to run a local node, how are you expecting to submit the transaction? The normal way of doing this is to use `cardano-cli` to first calculate the free and then use it to submit the transaction.

Comment: @ErikdeCastroLopo, I intend to submit it via Blockfrost.

Answer (score 3):

Transaction fees are computed based on two factors: size of the transactions, and required resources (memory and CPU steps).

[As Melroy van den Berg mentioned](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/8844/7225), transaction size increases the fee linearly:

```
fee_for_size = a * size(tx) + b
```

Both `a` and `b` are specified in *protocol paramaters*. You can get the latest parameters with Blockfrost using [this endpoint](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Epochs/paths/%7E1epochs%7E1%7Bnumber%7D%7E1parameters/get):

```
/epochs/latest/parameters
```

`min_fee_a` is the coefficient, while `min_fee_b` is the constant.

Blockfrost also provides [another endpoint](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Utilities/paths/%7E1utils%7E1txs%7E1evaluate/post) for finding the required resources for a given transaction (I don't remember the exact names used in its response, but let's call them `memory` and `steps`).

And if you [take another look at the protocol parameters](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Epochs/paths/%7E1epochs%7E1%7Bnumber%7D%7E1parameters/get), you may notice two other fields: `price_mem` and `price_step`. These are, respectively, price increases per memory and cpu steps. Therefore, you can compute your final transaction fee:

```
fee = fee_for_size + fee_for_execution

where:
fee_for_size      = a * size(tx) + b
fee_for_execution = memory * price_mem + steps * price_step
```

Comment: This only applies if you know your execution units. To find them out, you might want to use Blockfrost endpoint https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Utilities/paths/~1utils~1txs~1evaluate/post

Answer (score 0):

Fee calculation is actually pretty simple.

`0.155381 + 0.000044 * size`

Where `size` is the transaction size in bytes.

[More info](https://docs.cardano.org/explore-cardano/fee-structure)

Comment: This does not include the Smart Contract fee. The values you used are also subject to change,

Comment: answer could be improved by explaining where those numbers come from and be linking the documentation of that process.
This way users can set your comment as an answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use TyphonJs NPM library,

https://docs.strica.io/lib/typhonjs/classes/Transaction.html#getFee